# The shape is not getting changed within if and else if statements in Jfreechart

Tags: java, jfreechart

In a single series i.e in Time series chart different shapes have to obtained . But its not coming... pls refer the following code and tell me what mistake i have committed ?

```
      TimeSeriesCollection dataset = new TimeSeriesCollection(glucoseries);                                                
      JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart("Glucometer","Date","value",dataset,true,true,false);                           

     XYPlot xyplot = (XYPlot)chart.getPlot();
     XYLineAndShapeRenderer  renderer = (XYLineAndShapeRenderer) xyplot.getRenderer(); 

    int glucovalue = Integer.parseInt(glcvalue);

    if(glucovalue<80)
    {     
    renderer.setSeriesShape(0,new Ellipse2D.Double(-3.0,-3.0,8.0,8.0));
    renderer.setSeriesShapesVisible(0,true);
     }
    else if(glucovalue>80 && glucovalue<100)
    {               
    renderer.setSeriesShape(0,ShapeUtilities.createUpTriangle(4.0f));
    renderer.setSeriesShapesVisible(0,true);            
    }
    else if(glucovalue>100 && glucovalue< 120)
    {                   
    renderer.setSeriesShape(0,ShapeUtilities.createDiamond(4.0f));
    renderer.setSeriesShapesVisible(0,true);                    
    }
    else
    {
    renderer.setSeriesShape(0,ShapeUtilities.createDownTriangle(4.0f));
    renderer.setSeriesShapesVisible(0,true);                    
    }

     ChartRenderingInfo info = new ChartRenderingInfo(new StandardEntityCollection());
    File file1 = new File(request.getRealPath("\\jspchart\\gluco7.png"));
    ChartUtilities.saveChartAsPNG(file1, chart, 700, 400, info);
```

[image]

Comment: Is the code you have shown generating the suppled screenshot?

Comment: @GrahamA its not generated  ... but i need the output like the above screenshot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logic in your IF statement is only evaluated once, you need to subclass `XYLineAndShapeRenderer#getItemShape` to return a shape based on the current value.  Something like this

```java
    XYLineAndShapeRenderer renderer =  new XYLineAndShapeRenderer(true, true){
        Shape ellipse = new Ellipse2D.Double(-3.0,-3.0,8.0,8.0);
        Shape upTriangle = ShapeUtilities.createUpTriangle(4.0f);
        Shape diamond = ShapeUtilities.createDiamond(4.0f);
        Shape downTriangle = ShapeUtilities.createDownTriangle(4.0f);


        @Override
        public Shape getItemShape(int row, int column) {
            Double value = (Double) plot.getDataset(0).getY(row, column);
            if (value > 6.0 ) {
                return ellipse;
            } else if (value >= 5.0 ) {
                return upTriangle;
            } else if (value >= 2.0 ) {
                return diamond;
            }else {
                return downTriangle;
            }
        }

    };

  plot.setRenderer(renderer);
```

[image]

Comment: Since plot object is inside the method getItemShape() it cannot be identified and it is showing error at that point ....

Comment: Mark the plot as final.  Are you using an IDE? Eclipse will suggest this fix for you.

Comment: each different shape in a single series has to be filled with different colors .. I tried using renderer.setFillPaint() function but the renderer is not applicable ... Can u pls tell me where the renderer has to be exactly applied ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to figure out what is the value of : **glucovalue**

But one thing you have missed here is : you have not considered the boundary values correctly.

For eg :

```
 if(glucovalue<80)
{     
renderer.setSeriesShape(0,new Ellipse2D.Double(-3.0,-3.0,8.0,8.0));
renderer.setSeriesShapesVisible(0,true);
 }
else if(glucovalue>80 && glucovalue<100)
{
```

In the above code, none of the cases will match if `glucovalue = 80`

Change the code as follows :

```
 if(glucovalue<80)
{     
renderer.setSeriesShape(0,new Ellipse2D.Double(-3.0,-3.0,8.0,8.0));
renderer.setSeriesShapesVisible(0,true);
 }
else if(glucovalue>=80 && glucovalue<=100)
{
```

Comment: if so it will enter into else part ... but still shape is not getting changed

Comment: if you have else part, then how is it possible that nothing is getting executed. Do you get any exception ?